# Trying to paste entire workbooks at the bottom of another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

So it's working but it's pasting with 10 empty rows above and I am not sure why. [image: https://imgur.com/a/rJwsnFQ]

```
Sub Stuffff()

    Dim Rng As Range
    Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:AY300")
    Rng.Copy

    Dim s11 As Workbook
    Set s11 = Workbooks("11 Production")
    Dim last As Long
    Dim Rngnew As Range

With s11.Sheets("Sheet1")
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
        last = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                      After:=.Range("A1"), _
                      Lookat:=xlPart, _
                      LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                      MatchCase:=False).Row                 
    Else
        last = 1
    End If
End With
    Set Rngnew = s11.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & last + 1)

    Rngnew.PasteSpecial
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could try :

```
Sub Stuffff()

    Dim Rng As Range
    Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:AY300")
    Rng.Copy

    Dim s11 As Workbook
    Set s11 = Workbooks("11 Production")
    Dim last As Long
    Dim Rngnew As Range

With s11.Sheets("Sheet1")
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
        last = .range("A65000").end(xlup).offset(1,0).row               
    Else
        last = 1
    End If
End With
    Set Rngnew = s11.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & last)

    Rngnew.PasteSpecial
End Sub
```

That should work, unless you have more than 65 K rows in your workbook.

Comment: So thats working better but its still pasting with 2 empty rows

Comment: Are you sure that there are no empty rows in the range you copy and that there are no whitespace in the workbook in which you copy data? I would suggest deleting each row in the target workbook before running the code.

Comment: Ya sorry theres one empty row in what im copying but it still pastes with 2 empty rows above. Would a picture help?

Comment: Yes, please, both the end of the range which you want to copy and the range you copy it into

Comment: Glad i could help!